# Ellipsis not showing. Wassup?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/gKwb2/

see above.  i've tried and searched for many hours, now turning to you fine folks hoping you might have a nice easy solution.

i'm trying to show ellipsis for the 2nd box which has overflowing text.

any advice greatly appreciated!

my CSS:

```
.row-fluid { width: 95%; margin: auto; display: inline-block; height:100px; }

.span4 { 
    height:100px; 
    width: 100px; 
    float:left; 
    background: green; 
    border-bottom:solid 1px #fff;}

.container-fluid { 
    margin-left: 100px; 
    background: orange; 
    height:100px; 
    padding:0px;   
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

}

div { padding: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to show an ellipsis for wrapped text.  [Quirksmode says](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html):

> `text-overflow` comes into play only when:
>
> 1. the box has `overflow` other than `visible` (with `overflow: visible` the
>      text simply flows out of the box)
> 2. the box has `white-space: nowrap` or a
>      similar method of constraining the way the text is laid out. (Without
>      this, the text would wrap to the next line)

Answer (score 0):

There's a webkit solution for this, it's called `-webkit-line-clamp`

Just add the following class to your markup, and it will work in webkit browsers

```
<div class="container-fluid line-clamp">text</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gKwb2/2/)** (Check it out on a webkit browser)

```
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5; /* ellipsis on the 5th line of text */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

There's also a [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) which discusses this.

If you're looking for a cross-browser solution... well, I'm afraid that - to date - there isn't one.

There have been rather close attempts though.

As far as I am aware, [this article](http://kamlekar.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/ellipsis-on-second-line-using-pure-css/) gets the closest to a pure css cross-browser solution